# How to install apache tomcat to a custom directory?

Tags: apache-2.4, tomcat

When I go to `C:\Apache24\bin` and install apache using `httpd -k install`, it installs into `C:\Program Files`.

I am unable to do anything with the war files when this happens, because I always get the error

> java.io.IOException: Unable to create the directory

What must I write in the `C:\Apache24\httpd.conf` file to make it install to `C:\Apache Tomcat` instead of `C:\Program Files`?

Comment: Your question is asking about Apache HTTPD, not Apache Tomcat so please clarify what you actually want. However, you don't have to place your war files in `C:\Program Files` at all.

Answer (score 0):

First, `httpd -k install` only installs or registers Apache Httpd (which is not Tomcat) as a Windows service, so it has nothing to do with your problem. You must have installed Tomcat some other way, either using the Windows service installer or by unzipping the installation zip file.

Second, the directory where war files are located is defined in the `server.xml`:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="c:\whatever" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

The `appBase` attribute defines where the server will look and unpack its jar files.